# Removing item in list of strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to get rid of the newline `\n` character in a list of strings, this is my function:

```
def openFile(inputFile):
    pyFile = open(inputFile).readlines()

    for x in pyFile:
        x.rstrip('\n')

    return pyFile
```

This doesn't seem to work however.

Comment: `x.rstrip('\n')` creates *a new `str` object*; it doesn't alter `pyFile` at all.

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way to do this is:

```
with open(inputFile) as f:
    pyFile = f.read().splitlines()

for line in pyFile:
    print line
```

You read whole file as a single string and split it using `str.splitlines()` this removes newlines from the strings in your result.

Strings in Python are immutable, so every operations on them returns result as a copy, you cannot modify a string, though of course you can bind result to the same name:

```
a = 'foo'
a = 'foo'.upper()
print a
# 'FOO'
```

Answer (score 1):

string `strip`, `rstrip`, `lstrip` method doesn't affect the original string.

```
>>> b = "sss\n"
>>> b.strip()
'sss'
>>> b
'sss\n'
```

Comment: how would i go about removing it?

Comment: @KinseyR Actually there's no way to modify a string in Python cause string are immutable type. If you modify a string, what you actually did is create a new string and assign it to that variable.